# Multiple including a head file with a variable definition

Tags: c++

I just build a simple C++ project. The codes are shown in the follows:

-------- head.h --------

```
#ifndef _HEAD_H_
#define _HEAD_H_

int my_var = 100;

#endif
```

-------- src1.cpp --------

```
#include "head.h"
```

-------- src2.cpp --------

```
#include "head.h"
int main() { return 0; }
```

And I build the binary with those command:

```
g++ -c src1.cpp -o scr1.o
g++ -c src2.cpp -o src2.o
g++ -o a.out src2.o src1.o
```

But it fails in the linking step and tells me that i have "multiple definition of `my_var'. Did't I just use safe guard macros in the head file? I don't understand. Anyone know why?

thanks.

ps:
If I define my_var as **a static variable**, then the code can pass linking. I don't understand it either.

Comment: In all cases, try to mentally preprocess your source files, as if you were a GCC's preprocessor. Maybe it will bring some clarity. Also, it's worth saying, that in C++ you must avoid any global variables.

Answer (score 3):

Change the header the following way

```
#ifndef _HEAD_H_
#define _HEAD_H_

extern int my_var;

#endif
```

And for example add line in the module with main

```
#include "head.h"
int my_var = 100;
int main() { return 0; }
```

The problem is that as the header is included in two modules then each module contains a variable with external linkage with the same name as a variable in other module. And the linker does not know which variable to use.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining `my_var` once *per compilation unit*. Remember that include guards operate on a per compilation unit basis.

To remedy, you should *declare* `my_var` as `extern` in the header:

```
#ifndef _HEAD_H_
#define _HEAD_H_

extern int my_var;

#endif
```

and *define* it in one of the source files using

```
int my_var = 100;
```

Then the linker sees only one definition and all will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The guard only prevents the header from being included twice in the same compilation unit.

When you compile `src1.o` and `src2.o`, each one will contain a definition of `my_var`. When you link them to create `a.out`, the compiler cannot merge those definitions (even if they are identicals), and fails.

What you want to do is declare `my_var` as [extern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable) :

---- head.h ----

```
#ifndef _HEAD_H_
#define _HEAD_H_

extern int my_var;

#endif
```

---- my_var.c ----

```
#include "head.h"

int my_var = 100;
```

Then compile all source files :

```
g++ -c my_var.cpp -o my_var.o
g++ -c src1.cpp -o scr1.o
g++ -c src2.cpp -o src2.o
g++ -o a.out my_var.o src2.o src1.o
```

This way, `my_var` will be *declared* in every file, but will only be *defined* in `my_var.o`. There is an important difference here. Try to omit linking `my_var.o`, you'll see what the compiler has to say :)

Answer (score 0):

your problem boils down to understanding C++ storage classes; static and extern more precisely.

```
extern says: this variable is defined in a different file, this 
             is only a declaration
static says: this variable's lifetime is the program lifetime and
             restrict it's visibility to the current file. 



What happens in your case:
   - each file includes the variable declaration and definition `int my_var = 100;`,
     so both object scr1.o and scr2.o will contain the variable definition. When
     linking them, the linker cannot solve the ambiguity and throws an error.
   - adding the extern qualifier and defining the variable in one of the files 
     solves this problem: in one source it'll be an external unresolved at compile
     time, symbol and the other will contain the actual symbol.
```

As for the second part of your question; why adding static seems to help the linker. Look at what I just said about static storage class: basically each object will have their own copy of the variable - not the same one!

Comment: Why does static variable designed in C++ language? If one static variable defined in a head file is used in multiple cpp files, but actually each cpp file contains its own copy of the variable, is that a huge trap in the project?

Comment: ps: all the books say that static variable's visible only in the current file. Is the file only the head file or the cpp file include the head file? I think the static variable is visible to the cpp file including it.

Comment: what happens, because of the way you define the variable in the header file, each source file includes the variable definition as static; so their visibility is limited to the current file. From the compiler's point of view these are two separate variables